# Discrepancy between line plot and ACF plot for nonstationary time series

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, arima

I understand that when the ACF of a nonstationary time series is plotted it should show a very slow decay. I have data that clearly shows a trend, however the ACF shows a decay which seems to indicate that it is stationary and has no trend. Can someone tell me why this might happen?  Here is the plot of the data:

[image]

Now here is the plot of the ACF:

[image]

Comment: The plot is inadequate in not indicating how frequently the data are sampled.  It appears highly likely, though, that the data fall almost exclusively at the cusps of the graph.  In that case, you have such a short time series that the ACF plot is almost completely unreliable.  Consider exploring a much longer time series if you want to see what happens generally rather than getting distracted by accidental features.

Comment: @whuber In this case I averaged yearly data. So it's likely that the trend is accidental and not deterministic?